# is it good idea to pass jboss outbound connections through a web server?

Tags: apache, web, https, jboss

We are trying to integrate Jboss application to make Web services calls, so was wondering is it a good practice to make the web services call go through a web server always instead of handling SSL stuff by Jboss ?

Have this curious idea because if we want to implement authentication and make web server handle all the certificates for SSL so that in future if Jboss is replaced with a different technology the basic SSL configuration stills remains same in web server.

I agree for incoming requests to Jboss it makes sense to go through apache, but was wondering what about outbound connections from Jboss to a different provider ?

Any thoughts is very much appreciated.

Comment: How do you deal with internal security? I mean between Jboss and the incoming/outgoing request. Do you set ssl for these connections too? perhaps to dismiss sniffing...

Comment: We have a apache web server which acts as front for Jboss. All the requests go through apache which handles SSL authentication and then request goes to Jboss.